# can i Have nested rest webservice or open a link in webservice

Tags: java, web-services, restful-url

I am trying to open a link(s) from webservice can do so
or can i call the webservice witin the webservice

```
@Path("/testUrl")
public class TestResource {

@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
public void callUrl() throws Exception  {

    open("http://www.goggle.com");
    open("http://www.goggle.com");
    Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
    URI url1 = new URI("http://www.google.com");
    URI url2 = new URI("http://www.yahoo.com");
    desktop.browse(url1);
    desktop.browse(url2);
}

private void open(String url) throws Exception  {
    URL siteURL = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) siteURL.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.connect();

}
}
```

Comment: Of course a webservice can directly or indirectly access another url. Whether that makes sense and what to do with the returned data is up to you and your requirements. However, I'd like to add at least one observation: webservices are normally deployed on some server which in most cases don't have a UI (and thus no desktop either), so `Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();` probably won't work.

Comment: basical i wanna shedule a job in jenkins where job will call my webservice and within it i wanna call 3 more webservices

Comment: As I said that's perfectly possible. Just don't use `Desktop` since you'd most probably not have any but do it like any other programmatic webservice call (e.g. using `URL`, `Connection`, `HttpClient` etc.).